# Screen to move up when keypad invoked - Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing an Ionic v1 app. My expectation is, whenever an input field (like text, tel, email, number etc) is selected, the screen should goes up automatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

let's go to see. ionic is a hybrid framework for making mobile apps with angularJS. it uses HTML and in HTML, when you want goes up to an element selected, you have to set it a focus event. try set a focus event. I hope this can help you.